# Installing of graphic card driver amd

Tags: drivers, graphics, ati

hello im very new to ubuntu and would appreciate some help if possible, i read before i must install gpu drivers i had to update system so i did, then i went on AMD website and downloaded the driver version 15.7 and installed it, i followed this guide. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=evqpassbyqA , it didnt work then i read i should try to use system and update so i did the system update process again and tried then i booted up to a purple screen and then it proceed to go black after, i got amd 7660g and 7670m gpu's my laptop is a hp m6 1040eo would really appreciate all the help possible :)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to download anything from AMD web site.

The correct way of installing AMD drivers in Ubuntu is running in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates
```

But if you installed a driver another way, it may not work. You need to remove the other driver first.

Comment: How do i remove it if i cant get into the system? it boot up to purple screen then go black i tried holding shift in to enter tty1 mode i think its called? but it ask for login and when i write login it instant go black like there is no signal

Comment: It is difficult to explain if you never used Ubuntu before and also we do not know how exactly you installed the driver. The easiest and fastest way for you at this point will be to re-install Ubuntu and install the driver a correct way.

Comment: hello again so i tried reinstalling and then adding that command and then i rebooted like i would usually do but when my pc started up again the purple/pink screen came and then it proceeded to go black like there was no signal,

Comment: This means that the driver does not work well for your graphics. Press Ctrl+Alt+F1, login to console and run `sudo apt-get purge fglrx* && sudo reboot`.

Comment: what does this command do if i may ask and if it dosent work how do i get catalyst control manager?

Comment: This commands removes the driver and reboots. You can't use Catalyst if the driver does not work for your adapter.

Comment: is it possible getting an older driver which may work instead of the open source one?

Comment: You can try `sudo apt-get install fglrx`. It will install an older driver.